# How to increase texture mask opacity?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, masking

I'd like to stencil an image texture onto a surface; however it's not in the colors that I want. So, I instead use it as a texture mask. This allows me to paint with whatever color I want but still produce relative darknesses of the texture. However, the effect is too dim and I'd like to essentially increase the opacity of my texture mask. How do I do so?

Comment: hello could you please show screenshots of your interface so that we understand better what you mean?

Comment: If you are saying the paint going through the mask isn't thick enough to your taste, you may need to turn on Accumulate or adjust the contrast in your texture mask image prior to using it.

Comment: I read more about opacity masks and used curves to increase its contrast